# Use global planner to "DETECT" obstacles (not simply avoid or re-plan path)

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I'm not sure if this is a silly question that has a simple solution or if I missed something. However, using the Turtlebot 2 with the DWA planner and a known map when an obstacle causes a major re-planning of trajectory to its goal, but still succeeds in performing the task (i.e. causes the message) `DWA planner failed to produce path.`   the actionlib goal status doesn't have a message to deal with this. Therefore, if I want to count how many times an obstacle caused a path to be re-planned or I want to count how many times a robot encountered an obstacle I can't. ***(Note: This is true most of the time, as long as the obstacle doesn't cause enough of an issue for the robot to send an abort message to actionlib)***

Currently the robot immediately re-plans the path and continues until it gets to the goal (unless it can't reach the goal in which case it normally sends goalstatus.msg = 4, i.e. aborted). Did I miss something obvious, is there a way to check when a path is altered because of an obstacle? As a side note, no I don't want to use the camera to "detect" an obstacle in this case as it will defeat the point and do let me know if more information is required.

Thanks,
Tiz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290981/use-global-planner-to-%22detect%22-obstacles-(not-simply-avoid-or-re-plan-path)/) by [Tiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/34582/tiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since dwa failing to produce a path will result in the global planner being retriggered, you could listen to the global planner / plan topic.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/34582/tiz/) on 2018-05-29**:
Thanks. This might actually be the only possible way. Since no-one else has given better answers and I couldn't come up with anything better, I'll mark your answer as the solution. Hope it helps others as well.